# .Net Core Dictionary documentation

Tags: c#, .net-core

Can someone please tell me what does the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryAdd(TKey, TValue)` method do?

The documentation is weak, to say the least.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=netcore-2.0#Definition

I tried looking for the source:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic

But I can't find the source for the Dictionary class.

Edit: turns out the dictionary is source is in the CoreCLR repository, according to MarcinJuraszek.

Comment: The namespace definitely matches, as old collection types are under `System.Collection.NonGeneric`. In short, Microsoft did not plan to keep the old collection types, so `System.Collection` was used by the generic types.

Comment: Woops, my bad! You're correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is in CoreCLR repository ([click](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/391be015430d213365a1a5d09230f99f24a80de3/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L676)):

```
public bool TryAdd(TKey key, TValue value)
    => TryInsert(key, value, InsertionBehavior.None);
```

If you look at how `TryInsert` is implemented you'll see that it will add an element to the dictionary if one for a given key does not already exist. If an item with a given key already exists in the dictionary it will return `false` and will not modify the collection.

btw - the documentation you linked to [is also on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/e60a778d11d0bfc4a196ac16e592ec030772a757/xml/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary%602.xml#L2271), which means you should consider making it better for others to benefit from!